# XML deserialization Problem thru JAXB when using WebClient (Reactor)

Tags: project-reactor

I am trying to call a rest api thru WebClient. It is merely a simple call but somehow the response is not getting unmarshalled to object. Jaxb dependency is already present in pom.xml file. I am using bodyToMono method to convert the response body to object. But when I am passing the class type as String to collect the response body as string then I am able to get the response. Same thing is working if I use RestTemplate

Not Working (result is null):

```
ProductType result = webClient.get()
                              .uri("/products/{id}", "10835860")
                              .retrieve()
                              .bodyToMono(ProductType.class)
                              .block();
```

Working (result is xml as string):

```
String result = webClient.get()
                         .uri("/products/{id}", "10835860")
                         .retrieve()
                         .bodyToMono(String.class)
                         .block();
```

Could anyone pls help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Provide the code of your class ProductType. Provide example of responce XML that you get.

Comment: Thanks @mentallurg , you just pointed out the issue.

It's probably due to broken response which I am getting. Specially Root tag of xml is missing in response which should not be as per xsd. But I am just wondering why does RestTemplate not throwing any error during unmarshalaing, rather I can access the object & it is not null. In this scenario what is the best approach can I take to unmarshall it. Currently I am following some nasty approach, collecting the response as string then adding missing xml tag to comply with xsd at end unmarshalaing using jaxb.